# Can we track or logged SPIKED process in CPU on AWS Windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

We have AWS Windows t2.xlarge machine on which we deployed multiple application , every now and then , we face this issue that our application hangs because of high CPU, and then we need to restart to fix that issue.

Is there a way to track/monitor which process is causing that SPIKE (i;e using AWS Lambda)so that we can better scale our system and improve our monitoring capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cloudwatch agent with procstat](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-procstat-process-metrics.html) plugin to collect CPU usage of processes as custom metrics.

Comment: thanks for the response but
there are 3 types of configuration
1. PID based (we have to provide pid which want to monitor)
2. Exe based (we have to provide exe which we want to monitor)
3. Pattern based (we have to provide pattern eg: keywords for agents or plugins which we want to monitor)
first 2 will not work in our case becasue we dont know the pid or  exe which is causing cpu spike,in 3rd option we can search processes with wildcard pattern which consuming cpu but here scanning will cause cpu and we are using T2 instance type so we will use credit balance